# WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings just randomly appeared in my project, what is it?

Tags: xcode

The file `<MyProjectName>.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings` just randomly appeared in my project. Not sure if it was triggered by an Xcode update or what, but it just appeared. Its contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceSharedSettings_AutocreateContextsIfNeeded</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

No idea what `IDEWorkspaceSharedSettings_AutocreateContextsIfNeeded` is either.

I'm tempted to delete it is I don't want contexts (whatever this may mean) being autocreated without my knowledge.

Anybody know if I can do that without issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode -> "Manage Schemes" -> Turn on "Autocreate schemes" -> A update in
.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>IDEWorkspaceSharedSettings_AutocreateContextsIfNeeded</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Turning off "Autocreate schemes" is very helpful for projects that use CocoaPods, as the autocreation would create a scheme for each pod target, which is visually cluttering. [1]

#### Reference

[1] https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11327/IDEWorkspaceSharedSettingsAutocreateContextsIfNeeded-ignored